# A program to select rectangle on the screen

Tags: windows

I need a tool similar to the screen capturing ones but the functionality must be slightly different.

I want the tool to be able to select a rectangle on the screen and return its top left coordinates , width and height of the selected rectangle as text or copy the x,y,w,h in the clipboard.

If somebody knows such a tool i will be happy if he shares it with me.

10x in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can easily code in one of those macro automation languages, like AutoHotkey or autoIt. The syntax is easy, AHK looks like javascript, AutoIt like VB.

This command would be something you would be interested in.

[MouseGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm)